# Task using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

An integer matrix of size 5x5 is given. Replace all negative elements of the first row in this matrix with the number 0.

I understand that you need to cycle through the matrix, but I don't fully understand how to do it. Please explain, because I want to learn how to solve such problems.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is expected to do some level of searching and minimal working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to solve your problem by going through and example.

```
import numpy as np
#create matrix of size (5,5) with all zeros
matrix = np.zeros((5,5))
#since you are curious about first row, I will change the elements of the 1st row only
matrix[0][0] = 1
matrix[0][1] = -10
matrix[0][2] = 5
matrix[0][3] = -12
matrix[0][4] = -18
#loop through only the first row
for i in range(5):
#checking if number is negative
    if matrix[0][i] < 0:
        matrix[0][i] = 0

print(matrix)
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import numpy as np
 #create matrix of size (5,5) with all zeros
 matrix = np.zeros((5,5))
 matrix[0]=[1,-2,3,-4,-5]
 matrix[0]=np.where(matrix[0]<0,0,matrix[0])
```

[image]

Explanation: After importing numpy, initialized a matrix of 0s of size 5x5 & assigned some values (both +ve & -ve to the 1st row). Now using np.where() for the 1st row of the matrix, assigned 0 to -ve values & +ve values remain unchanged. np.where() takes 1st argument as a condition, 2nd argument is what to do if condition is true else what to do when condition is false in 3rd argument

Answer (score 0):

> "init_array" is your 5x5 matrix.

```
import numpy as np 
result = np.where(init_array[0]<0, 0, init_array[0])
```

your **init_array** of *5x5* matrix must be initialised

it will check in first row elements using **init_array[0]** whenever it will be less then zero then it will replace it with **zero**

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)